# Forgot item in a hotel in Spain; hotel says I have to send a courier myself because they don't handle international shipments

Tags: spain, shipping, lost-luggage

I recently returned from a trip to Europe. (I live in the United States.) On my way back I had a layover in Madrid and I forgot a coat in the hotel room I stayed at. I contacted the hotel and they said that they have the coat, but that they can't ship it internationally. They told me in an email:

> We don't handle international shipments as we can´t full fill [sic] customs paperwork.
>   I suggest that you contact a courier company to pick up the forgotten item and let us know the pick up date in order to have it prepared.

Two ways I can see to resolve my issue:

1. I send a courier as they suggested. What companies offer this kind of service, and how do I find it? I looked on UPS and DHL but didn't see anything obvious.
2. I fill out a customs form for them and they use that to ship the item. Is this possible?

Are either of those two alternatives possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: DHL certainly offer a wide range of international shipping services, including handling the customs work. However, they're focussed on business, so you'd have to ask them if they will handle a single transaction for you. You'd have to ask the hotel if they'd accept a customs for prepared by you. They'd probably stiill expect you to arrange shipment.  In either case there's a good chance that the cost of recovering the lost item will come close to the cost of replacing it.

Comment: Spending $200 to ship a used coat whose replacement value is ~$200(?) Doesn't sound cost-effective to me. Are you paying for this or is your employer? Unless it's a really expensive coat...

Comment: @smci: The coat might have sentimental value, e.g. a present from a relative.  Or even without that, a good quality coat can easily cost over $200.

Comment: It's a good quality coat. Also, I've shipped stuff from Germany to the US and it's been between $20–$50. Is it more expensive to ship from Spain?

Comment: May I suggest you rephrase the title of the question? Sounds a bit aggressive to me for what is a perfectly reasonable policy on the hotel's side.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez Native English speaker here and I don’t agree. The title spells out the facts and isn’t unnecessarily aggressive or melodramatic IMO.

Comment: Be prepared for shipping to cost more than the coat.  Unless it's the custom Batman coat from Outlander Season 3, might not be worth bothering.

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf: the OP originally said 'courier' and that will cost way more than $20 for a bulky item like a coat.

Comment: @Darren "hotel says..." Somehow implies that they are making excuses. "Hotel can't send it back to me" would be more accurate.. "How can I recover a expensive item left at a hotel abroad?" may be even better.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez well there is nothing actually stopping the hotel shipping the coat back apart from their own policy so “says” is accurate. “Can’t” or “unable” would imply a technical reason they couldn’t.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez "hotel says..." is a fact. The hotel _did_ say that. Another fact is that the hotel _could_ ship this item internationally. They just don't want to. Considering this person was the hotel's customer, this is poor customer service. While this might be typical for hotels, wording the question this way makes perfect sense. A _great_ hotel would ship it to keep their customer happy.

Comment: just went through that in Poland; and there was no problem for the courier to pick the item up at the hotel.

Comment: Method II: (dramatic drumroll) Buy a new coat.

Comment: @ApologizeandreinstateMonica The reason they don't do international shipping is simple. If there are drugs, or some other illegal material within the coat, they would find themselves in serious trouble when it crosses international borders. They simply cannot vouch for the integrity of the package, so in a sense, they can't fill out the customs paperwork. They may be able to investigate ways they can mitigate their liability in this scenario, but it's far easier on everyone for a dedicated courier company to handle this situation.

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf - it's a pretty big item, I bet it will be about $100

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - Good thinking.  funny thing, I've never thought of that.  I've known of hotels ship things (internationally) a number of times and the issue never arose. What you say is logical but (I guess just coincidentally) my experience has been the same as what Apologize sed.

Comment: I feel all the comments questioning the value of the coat are borderline *rude* guys!  It is unimaginable I would leave a coat, sweater etc. in a hotel and not pay the $100 to have it sent back to me.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**UPS, DHL, and pretty much any courier company can deliver from anywhere to anywhere**, they don't require that the person handing them the package is the same person as the one paying the bill.  So ask the hotel to pack up the coat and tell you the box/package weight & dimensions, then go to the courier website and fill in a package pickup request with the hotel's address & contact info, your home address for delivery, and your credit card for payment.  Let the hotel know when they're coming and that's it.

Source: I've done this and it worked fine.

Comment: I did the same thing for Australia, book it and let hotel know when they are coming to pick up easy as that

Comment: Additionally, give the hotel the tracking number, in case the UPS/DHL/courier is late or to avoid that they say that they "gave it to the guy".

Comment: Also, this makes *you* the customer, i.e. you will be able to resolve problems without having to contact the hotel again.

Comment: You could also prepare the customs paperwork, attach it to a pre-paid, pre-addressed box for the carrier of your choice, and ship that box along with a letter of instructions (and maybe a 20 euro note for their trouble) to the hotel management.

Comment: _ ask the hotel to pack up the coat_ Good luck with that. The hotel have no obligation beyond keeping the item until the OP arranges collection. Or until six months or some reasonable time elapses, after which they can drop it off at a charity shop or the bin.

Comment: @OscarBravo The hotel already offered the courier pickup option.

Comment: @spuck Welcome to Travel.SE. If you have an answer to this question, can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 23):

> I looked on UPS and DHL but didn't see anything obvious.

For DHL, the service you need is called [scheduled pickup](https://mydhl.express.dhl/es/en/schedule-pickup.html). You essentially arrange the shipping as usual, but you pay extra for your parcel to be picked up by a courier. Once you pay for your shipment, you'll get a DHL shipping label which you'll have to send to the hotel. They will print the label, attach it to the box containing your coat and give it to the DHL courier on a given date and time.

Understand that the hotel is already doing you a favour if they are not asking you to pay for their trouble. The reason they cannot ship your coat themselves (besides shipping costs) is liability: if your coat is seized at the customs, the last thing they want is to be listed as the origin of the parcel.

Comment: Those last few sentences actually explain a lot. Nice.

Comment: When staff members could be facing jail for drug trafficking (for example), that's a hell of a valid reason.

Comment: I would ask the hotel how much I owe them, to indicate that I'm not requesting them to work for free.